# picking the 10 largest values in array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, fortran, quicksort, fortran90

I want to pick the 10 largest values in an array (size~1e9 elements) in fortran 90. what is the most time efficient way to do this? I was looking into efficient sorting algorithm, is it the way to go? Do I need to sort the entire array?

Comment: you have to sort the array and lookup in that or iterate through the entire array each time you pick.

Comment: You may wish to look into [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

Comment: Mostly quickselect isn't going to perform as well as something like @dasblinkenlight 's solution -- you're going to want to minimize the number of times you read the relatively large amount of data.

Answer (score 5):

Sorting 10<sup>9</sup> elements to pick 10<sup>1</sup> from the top sounds like an overkill: log<sub>2</sub>N factor will be about 30, and the process of sorting will move a lot of data.

Make an array of ten items for the result, fill it with the first ten elements from the big array, and sort your 10-element array. Now walk the big array starting at element 11. If the current element is greater than the smallest item in the 10-element array, find the insertion point, shift ten-element array to make space for the new element, and place it in the array. Once you are done with the big array, the small array contains ten largest values.

For "larger values of ten" you can get a significant performance improvement by switching to a [max-heap data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). Construct a heap from the first ten items of the big array; store the smallest number for future reference. Then for each number in the big array above the smallest number in the heap so far do the following:

- Replace the smallest number with the new number,
- Follow the heap structure up to the root to place the number in the correct spot,
- Store the location of the new smallest number in the heap.

Once you are done, the heap will contain ten largest items from the big array.

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but instead of inserting the new element, just replacing the last element with the newest element and quicksorting the 10-size array. how bad is that?

Comment: @simona This isn't bad either, I'm not sure if you'd see much difference.

Comment: @simona For 10 items quicksort will be much slower than a simple insertion sort.

Comment: Why not a 10-element max-heap? It's barely more difficult to code than the insertion sort, and slightly more efficient (especially if "10" can be larger) since it runs in O(N log K) rather than O(NK) time.

Comment: @PaulHankin "The algorithm may be inefficient for larger values of ten" is pretty cool :-) With ten items or less it almost does not matter what you do, because your writes will happen for the most part in cache. In the worst case max-heap would probably be twice as fast, but in a random case it will probably be a wash.

Comment: the comment of @PaulHankin is relevant because in fact my 10 can get pretty big.

Comment: It's easy to test anyway -- try both the array insertion and heap versions, and see which is faster on your data and for whatever value of 10 you have :)

Comment: I agree with @dasblinkenlight that it probably doesn't make much difference on average -- the average number of insertions grows like log(N) if the array is randomly sorted, so the cost of reading the data dominates if Klog(N) is much smaller than N.

Comment: That's not the optimum solution. A max-heap is not efficient in seeking the minimum element. Better use the **min-heap** instead – then the minimum item (the one to be replaced) is available at the heap's top. Then you can immediately test if the new coming item is less than the top or bigger than it, and decide to discard it or put it in the heap, respectively. No need to seek the least item and store its position anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is not needed. You just need a priority queue of size 10, cost O(n) while the best sort is O(nlogn).

Comment: could you explain? because it seems like you are referring to a precise algorithm but I am not sure

Comment: You put in a priority queue every number, the priority of the queue has to be how big is that number. Then the first 10 elements of the queue will be the biggest elements in your 10e9 array

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to perform a full sorting. You can drop parts of an input array as soon as you know they contain only items from those largest 10, or none of them.

You could for example adapt a quicksort algorithm in such a way that you recursively process only partitions covering the border between the 10-th and the 11-th highest items. Eventually you'll get 10 largest items at 10 last positions (not necessarily ordered by value, though) and all other items below (not in order, either).
Anyway in pessimistic case (wrong pivot selection or too many equal items) it may take too long.

The best solution is passing the big array through a 10-item priority queue, as @J63 mentions in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42530662/733637).

Comment: I often take an approach where I evolve the code. If this is the last thing to do then you may need the sort. But I would start by trying MAXLOC and use a mask and run it 10 passes storing the locations and masking false the each one as you go. That should be optimal for N=1 and poor when sorting the whole thing... But 10 is pretty close to 1.